# right angle T in a circle - how long are the lines?

Tags: geometry, intersection

I was playing around with sketchup earlier and I drew this. It made me think because if you have to draw a right angled T shape in a circle to subdivide the 3 sections equally, you have to work out where the lines intersect somehow. I got this by trial and error with sketchup thanks to tweaking. It's accurate to about 3 decimal places. Original circle is 1000mm radius to keep things simple. The line that intersects the center of the circle ended up being 1264.9~. My question is why did the line end up having to be this rather odd and exact length? Each area of the circle is equal (at least according to sketchup) in mm2.

Circle with equal areas subdivided with a T:

[image: img]

Applications for something like this would be in areas like art and garden design where equal areas of canvas or garden need to be planted proportionately. Are there any existing examples of something like already in existence?

Comment: What do you find odd about the length 1264.9?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has no relation to programming

Comment: this is pure math so +Close. You want to find horizontal line which divides you circle area into `1/3` and `2/3` parts. So you need to find or derive the equation of the section depending on cuting line `y` coordinate and compute `y` from it so the are is `1/3` of full circle. ... as `Pi` and goniometrics are involved do not expect nice numbers

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about geometry and [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Comment: Yeah, that's fair enough. I was thinking of using it to design a packing schema for cargo planes

Comment: If you can take the area of the circle and divide it by 3 then the  first line will effectively draw the other two because the perpendicular line will arise from its halfway point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a circle of radius 1, the area of a segment of aperture `Θ` is `(Θ - sin Θ) / 2` (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_segment#Area). So the aperture of the lower segment is given by the transcendental equation

```
(Θ - sin Θ) / 2 = π / 3.
```

By numerical methods, `Θ = 2.6053256746009...`

Then the height of the two curvilinear triangles is

```
1 + cos Θ/2 = 1.26493208460278...
```

There is no closed-forma expression for this length (more than likely irrational).

Comment: Thanks Yves,

I'll run it past the match club in my old alma mater. They might be able to come with a formula for it. It was my lack of mathematical vocabulary that was the main stumbling block. Glad to hear I'm getting closer to transcendence ;)

Comment: @Eoghan: I doubt there is a formula.

Comment: I thought of another use for this. If you're like me and have OCD all the time about everything, you could use this formula to make sure you eat an equal amount of digestive biscuit with each dunk. Eating a chocolate digestive in 3 bites that has been dunked in tea for the correct amount of time is thus a useful preparation for construction robots on their tea break. 

I think it could prove useful to allow them to determine the depth of dunk